# form submit via ajax with fieldset

Tags: javascript

I'm using form submit via ajax but within a fieldset ,it is not working even when i'm try putting an alert to check if it is working. but when i'm removing the fieldset , its actually submitting, can you tell me what's wrong on this code?

```
 <form method="POST" name="StudentForm" id="StudentForm">
      <fieldset>
        <h4>Student Name</h4>
        FirstName: <input type="text" name="FirstName"><br>
        MiddleName: <input type="text" name="MiddleName"><br>
        LastName: <input type="text" name="LastName">
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset>
        <legend>Info:</legend>
        ContactNumber: <input type="text" name="ContactNumber"><br>
        Address: <input type="text" name="Address"><br>

      </fieldset>
    </form>        
    $(document).on('submit', '#StudentForm', function (e)
                   {

         e.preventDefault(); //form will not submitted
            $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("StudentSubmit")",
                            method: "POST",
                            data: new FormData(this),
                            contentType: false,       
                            cache: false,                
                            processData: false,                                    
                            success: function (data) {        
                                try {

                                    location.reload();
                                }
                                catch{
                                    alert("Error! Please Contact Administrator.")
                                }
                            },
                     error: function (errormessage) {
                         alert(errormessage.responseText);
                      }
               });
       });
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
<form method="POST" name="StudentForms" id="StudentForms">
<fieldset>
    <h4>Student Name</h4>
    FirstName: <input type="text" name="FirstName"><br>
    MiddleName: <input type="text" name="MiddleName"><br>
    LastName: <input type="text" name="LastName">
    <button type="submit">save</button>
</fieldset>
 <fieldset>
    <legend>Info:</legend>
    ContactNumber: <input type="text" name="ContactNumber"><br>
    Address: <input type="text" name="Address"><br>

  </fieldset>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).on('submit', '#StudentForms', function (e){
     e.preventDefault(); 
     $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "yor_api_url",
                  data: $('#StudentForms').serialize(),
                  cache: false,
                  success: function(data)
                  {
                     console.log(data)
                  },
                  error: function(data)
                  {
                    console.log(data)
                  }
            })
    });
</script>
```